# WiX using partial merge module

Tags: wix, windows-installer, merge-module

I have an install project that installs some files in the default feature. I also have a merge module that overlaps and contains some files that the install project already has. Due to the merge module being used in other projects, I cannot change it. The default behavior of the install project also cannot be changed. On build, I am still able to get the .msi output but also receive the following error:

`ICE30: The target file 'file' is installed in 'dir' by two different components on an LFN system: 'cmp1' and 'cmp2'. This breaks component reference counting.`

Is there a way to solve this scenario? I have looked for ways to install parts of a merge module but haven't found anything.

Comment: What merge module is this? "Home-grown"?

Comment: Yes, it is used by another department so I cannot remove the duplicate files from it

Comment: What folders do this merge module target? It must be a retargetable module? Does it install some files to shared locations? System?

Comment: The other department needs to take your feature request and create the variation points you need.